# Confusing about the Cglib MethodInterceptor invoke method

Tags: java, aop, cglib

I have some confuses about the Cglib MethodInterceptor,as the document describe:
  All generated proxied methods call this method instead of the original method. The original method may either be invoked by normal reflection using the Method object, or by using the MethodProxy (faster).

But the code below has error cause by the java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;why?
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class CglibInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {
@Override
public Object intercept(Object obj, Method method, Object[] args, MethodProxy proxy) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(" CglibInterceptor do something");
    return method.invoke(obj, args);

}
```

}

Comment: I debug the method just now,the first paramter Object obj is the dynamic proxy class created by the cglib,so the method.invoke(obj, args) throw the exception.if i set the original proxied obj to the CglibInterceptor,and method.invoke(originalProxiedObject, args) the problem is fixed

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted creates an endless loop. The difference between using normal reflection and the `MethodProxy` is that the `MethodProxy` will call the subclass implementation of the proxied class while the reflective invocation will be proxied again.

You can think of the two options as follows:

```
 class NormalClass {
   void m() { }
 }

 class CglibClass extends NormalClass {
   void m() {
     // This would be like the reflective invocation
     this.m();
     // This has the same effect as the MethodProxy
     super.m();
   }
 }
```

The problem is that reflective invocations are bound dynamically. Therefore, they will always hit the proxy which is nothing more than a dynamically created subclass. Choosing one of the two invocation options is not about speed, it is about whether you want to hit the proxy or not.

Answer (score 1):

I think the decompile result can make things more clear.

For a proxy instance that cglib create. It override the original method like this. It was a enhanced method so it will redirect your call to the intercept method. passed with 4 parameter.

```java
public final boolean equals(Object var1) {
        MethodInterceptor var10000 = this.CGLIB$CALLBACK_0;
        if (var10000 == null) {
            CGLIB$BIND_CALLBACKS(this);
            var10000 = this.CGLIB$CALLBACK_0;
        }

        if (var10000 != null) {
            Object var2 = var10000.intercept(this, CGLIB$equals$0$Method, new Object[]{var1}, CGLIB$equals$0$Proxy);
            return var2 == null ? false : (Boolean)var2;
        } else {
            return super.equals(var1);
        }
```

The second parameter is method and it was init like this.

```java
Method[] var10000 = ReflectUtils.findMethods(new String[]{"equals", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z", "setName", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", "hello", "()V", "sayHello", "()V"}, (var1 = Class.forName("main.webapp.cglib.PersonProxy")).getDeclaredMethods());
CGLIB$equals$0$Method = var10000[0];
```

so when you call method.invoke() on a enhancer object it just find the enhanced method like equals() below not the original method .

And methodProxy is just a class who knows the original method' name and enhanced method's name so when you call invokeSuper() it just call original method and will not be redirected to the enhanced method.

```java
CGLIB$equals$0$Proxy = MethodProxy.create(var1, var0, "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z", "equals", "CGLIB$equals$0");
```

```java
public class PersonProxy$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$adb7ea84 extends PersonProxy implements Factory {
    private boolean CGLIB$BOUND;
    public static Object CGLIB$FACTORY_DATA;
    private static final ThreadLocal CGLIB$THREAD_CALLBACKS;
    private static final Callback[] CGLIB$STATIC_CALLBACKS;
    private MethodInterceptor CGLIB$CALLBACK_0;
    private static Object CGLIB$CALLBACK_FILTER;
    private static final Method CGLIB$equals$0$Method;
    private static final MethodProxy CGLIB$equals$0$Proxy;
    private static final Object[] CGLIB$emptyArgs;
    private static final Method CGLIB$setName$1$Method;
    private static final MethodProxy CGLIB$setName$1$Proxy;
    private static final Method CGLIB$hello$2$Method;
    private static final MethodProxy CGLIB$hello$2$Proxy;
    private static final Method CGLIB$sayHello$3$Method;
    private static final MethodProxy CGLIB$sayHello$3$Proxy;
    private static final Method CGLIB$toString$4$Method;
    private static final MethodProxy CGLIB$toString$4$Proxy;
    private static final Method CGLIB$hashCode$5$Method;
    private static final MethodProxy CGLIB$hashCode$5$Proxy;
    private static final Method CGLIB$clone$6$Method;
    private static final MethodProxy CGLIB$clone$6$Proxy;

    static void CGLIB$STATICHOOK1() {
        CGLIB$THREAD_CALLBACKS = new ThreadLocal();
        CGLIB$emptyArgs = new Object[0];
        Class var0 = Class.forName("main.webapp.cglib.PersonProxy$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$adb7ea84");
        Class var1;
        Method[] var10000 = ReflectUtils.findMethods(new String[]{"equals", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z", "setName", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", "hello", "()V", "sayHello", "()V"}, (var1 = Class.forName("main.webapp.cglib.PersonProxy")).getDeclaredMethods());
        CGLIB$equals$0$Method = var10000[0];
        CGLIB$equals$0$Proxy = MethodProxy.create(var1, var0, "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z", "equals", "CGLIB$equals$0");
        CGLIB$setName$1$Method = var10000[1];
        CGLIB$setName$1$Proxy = MethodProxy.create(var1, var0, "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", "setName", "CGLIB$setName$1");
        CGLIB$hello$2$Method = var10000[2];
        CGLIB$hello$2$Proxy = MethodProxy.create(var1, var0, "()V", "hello", "CGLIB$hello$2");
        CGLIB$sayHello$3$Method = var10000[3];
        CGLIB$sayHello$3$Proxy = MethodProxy.create(var1, var0, "()V", "sayHello", "CGLIB$sayHello$3");
        var10000 = ReflectUtils.findMethods(new String[]{"toString", "()Ljava/lang/String;", "hashCode", "()I", "clone", "()Ljava/lang/Object;"}, (var1 = Class.forName("java.lang.Object")).getDeclaredMethods());
        CGLIB$toString$4$Method = var10000[0];
        CGLIB$toString$4$Proxy = MethodProxy.create(var1, var0, "()Ljava/lang/String;", "toString", "CGLIB$toString$4");
        CGLIB$hashCode$5$Method = var10000[1];
        CGLIB$hashCode$5$Proxy = MethodProxy.create(var1, var0, "()I", "hashCode", "CGLIB$hashCode$5");
        CGLIB$clone$6$Method = var10000[2];
        CGLIB$clone$6$Proxy = MethodProxy.create(var1, var0, "()Ljava/lang/Object;", "clone", "CGLIB$clone$6");
    }

    final boolean CGLIB$equals$0(Object var1) {
        return super.equals(var1);
    }

    public final boolean equals(Object var1) {
        MethodInterceptor var10000 = this.CGLIB$CALLBACK_0;
        if (var10000 == null) {
            CGLIB$BIND_CALLBACKS(this);
            var10000 = this.CGLIB$CALLBACK_0;
        }

        if (var10000 != null) {
            Object var2 = var10000.intercept(this, CGLIB$equals$0$Method, new Object[]{var1}, CGLIB$equals$0$Proxy);
            return var2 == null ? false : (Boolean)var2;
        } else {
            return super.equals(var1);
        }
    }
```